# Trouble in creating file java

Tags: java, eclipse

currently I'm working on a project and I have to change the savepath of my application. So I will firstly check if the directory exists using

```
File file = new File(path);
file.exists();
```

My problem is that the method file.exists() returns false even when I try to input C: as my path. Nevertheless, if I don't specify any folder, let say :

```
File file = new File("testFile.xml");
```

Then the new file will be created in the main directory. I suspect Eclipse automatically adds a relative path everytime I do the check since when I use text editor, the following returns true

```
new File("C:").exists()
```

Now, is there any way to tell Eclipse to recognise the path that I enter as an absolute path?

Thanks!

EDITED ****

I found that my problem is that Eclipse seems to auto append every file path that I create with the source directory

```
File = new File("C:/")
```

will give me

```
"C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\School Stuff\CS2103\JOBS\main\C:\"
```

which is automatically appended by eclipse with the project directory and hence, disabling me from creating file outside of my project directory

Comment: Did you try to use an absolute path for example `C:/`?

Comment: Full paths start with an `/`.

Comment: I tried /C:/ and it still fails

Comment: C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\School Stuff\CS2103\JOBS\main\C:\Users this is the full path when I typed /C:/Users

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()` ?

Answer (score 0):

[File.isAbsolute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isAbsolute%28%29):

```
File file = new File(path);
if (file.isAbsolute()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse, right click on project and go to run> run configuration and go to arguments give the default path for saving file.... project always create file on that location.

```
            File fileTest = new File("C:/test");
            if (!fileTest.exists()) {
                if (fileTest.mkdirs()) {
                    fileTest.setReadable(true, false);
                    fileTest.setWritable(true, false);
                } else {
                System.out.println("Failed To Create Directories! :-"+ "C:/");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I don't want to alter the current path since most of the loading assumes relative path, but I want to be able to load full path as well